# How to stylize a copyright bar with responsive properties

Tags: html, css

I want a copyright bar that has one phrase on the left, and another phrase on the right. However, when I try to minimize the widow size, things start going awry. I've tried centering the text when I make the window smaller so that when they sack on top of one another, it looks more pleasing to the eye, but now my bottom div is overlapping the top one. Here's what I want my copyright bar to look like:

https://amazingwebsites.co/

Here's the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hjngcLd/

I'm mostly having problems with the right section. Here's the CSS for that one:

```
#copyright-right {
float : right;
font-size : 1.5em;
color : #222222;
padding-top : 8px;
padding-left : 20%;
font-family : 'Roboto condensed';
font-weight : 300;
letter-spacing : 0;
padding-right : 20%;
background-color : #B5B7B9;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has to do with your media query:

```
@media (max-width: 1400px)
  #copyright-right {
      top: -8px;
  }
```

Ensure that property isn't set at the appropriate viewport width and you won't get the overlap. Right now you apply it to any viewport width up to 1400px wide.

Comment: Wow, didn't even see that. Thank you for checking that for me.